# Node.js and socket.io don't work on Cloud9 IDE

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cloud9-ide

Does anyone has experience to have Node.js and socket.io working on Cloud9 IDE?

The "Example (NodeJS with Socket.io)" (at https://c9.io/site/blog/2013/05/native-websockets-support/) doesn't work.

First, the server (https://c9.io/etlolap/webapp, /test.js) throws an error unless I fix as follow. I clicked Run button while test.js is on active tab.

```
var 
  socketIo = require('socket.io'),
  io = socketIo.listen(Number(process.env.PORT));
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Then, my client (https://c9.io/etlolap/webapp, /test.html) still cannot connect. I clicked Preview button while test.html is on active tab.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect('https://webapp-c9-etlolap.c9.io');
      socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Loading...
  </body>
</html>
```

and got error message below.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 --- (Not Found) https://c9.io/socket.io/socket.io.js
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined               --- test.html:6

Comment: I gave up and used a different solution.

Comment: Cloud9 and socket.io work fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for feedback from damphat and Matthias. After many failed attempts, finally I figured out the solution myself.
On Cloud9 IDE, the typical line in client (test.html here) has to be changed from,

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

to

```
 <script src="https://webapp-c9-etlolap.c9.io/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

The prefix is the URL of your Cloud9 project URL. By changing this line, my example worked.

Comment: Glad we could help. Even though I had the same issue in my application, working around it with the static file.

Comment: Excuse me, Matthias. I think my solution is more concise and straightforward.

Comment: will double slash work ? I think the problem is http vs https ,with "//" script can figure it out itself

Answer (score 10):

**1. Steps**

1.1) `Run` server.js

[image]

The cloud 9 console shows up:

[image]

1.2) Hit `Preview` on index.html

[image]

1.3) Then a window is opening on the right side of your IDE. You can either hit the button in the middle of the navigation bar or copy and paste the url into a new browser window.

[image]

1.4) Socket communication is working!

[image]

[image]

**2. Prerequisite**

2.1) node module socket.io

Hit `F6` or `View -> Console` and install socket.io.

[image]

2.2) the client side JavaScript from socket.io

Since I didn't find an official link to download it, I created a GitHubGist.

[socket.io.js](https://gist.github.com/MatthiasHoldorf/7957556)

**3. Code**

**server.js**

```
// module dependencies
var http = require("http"),
    sio  = require("socket.io");

// create http server
var server = http.createServer().listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP),

// create socket server
io = sio.listen(server);

// set socket.io debugging
io.set('log level', 1);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.emit('news', { message: 'Hello world!' });

  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data.message);
  });

});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

        <script src="js/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>

        var socket = io.connect("https://demo-project-c9-matthiasholdorf.c9.io");

        socket.on("news", function(data) {
            console.log(data.message);
        });

        socket.emit("my other event", { message : "client emit" } );

        </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you manually create a static file "socket.io.js" under project folder /js? But I learned that, once a node server containing socket.io.js starts, the file "socket.io.js" would be magically created under folder /socket.io. Though I don't know the exact mechanism.

Comment: Yes, I did. But you are right, there is indeed a builder for the client side JavaScript in the socket.io node module. You should be able to address the client side JavaScript from socket.io through [this](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/client/socket.io.js) path. It didn't work for me in the hurry, so I went with a static file.

Comment: Mathhias, can you run the client remotely ? because i can't get this working

Answer (score 0):

you must flowing these step:

open the terminal on https://c9.io/etlolap/webapp, type:

```
npm install socket.io
node test
```

then open a new tab of browser with url

```
https://webapp-c9-etlolap.c9.io/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

You will see socket.io.js source code

---

I did not how you open test.html in c9.io without http server, did you just press preview?

---

Edit:

To return html files, you should merge http server and socket.io server like this:

```
// file: test.js
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen( Number( process.env.PORT ) );

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/test.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: I have added my steps how I executed the files. Can you point out if anything wrong?

Comment: I can see the socket.io.js per your steps. But I didn't get how it could fix my issue? Hitting https://c9.io/etlolap/webapp/workspace/test.html still get me the 404 error msg.

Comment: you should merge web server and socket.io server into 1 app, see my update

Comment: The original example from Cloud9 IDE (at https://c9.io/site/blog/2013/05/native-websockets-support/) didn't require to merge web server and socket.io server. Anyway, I have tried your codes but still get the same 404 error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fetch any html file requested, using html files located in the file folder, you can use express:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// This fetches html files from the client folder (if they exist), and returns a "Page could not be found" error otherwise (this can be customized to some other 404 error page as desired)
app.get('*', function (req, res) {

    var urlReading = req.url;
    if (urlReading == "/")
    {
        urlReading = "/index.html";
    }
    urlReading = __dirname + "/client" + urlReading;

    console.log("Loading: " + urlReading);

    fs.readFile(urlReading, function (err, html) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Could not find " + urlReading)
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.end("<html><head><title>Page could not be found</title></head><body><h1>Page could not be found</h1></body></html>");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Found " + urlReading)
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.end(html);
        }

    });
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```