# Socket server with Node.js and Cloud9 IDE

Tags: node.js, sockets, cloud9-ide

I am totally new to Cloud9 IDE, so my question amy be silly, but i can't find answer in docs. I want to make client - server application with Node.js + MongoDB as socket server, and client  - desktop application which I debug and run on my machine (Cloud9 IDE doesn't support language on which I write it). Looking at Cloud9 IDE I've found it very nice for developing server-side part of my application and may be as hosting solution. But I can't find how to make socket connection from client. For this I need to know IP adress or domain address of my server (I suppose it looks like  "https://socialcrm-c9-painkkkiller.c9.io") and port number.
In docs I've found about "use process.env.PORT as the port and process.env.IP as the host in your scripts!" but to connect to server I need they real values! Commands
console.log(process.env.PORT) and console.log(process.env.IP) gives me just "8080" and 0.0.0.0
Using "https://socialcrm-c9-painkkkiller.c9.io" as domain and 8080 as port gives me socket error. So is it possible at all? And if possible how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579747/node-js-and-socket-io-dont-work-on-cloud9-ide

Comment: I've read this before posting question It didn't help me.

Answer (score 3):

Cloud9 forwards port 80 of https://socialcrm-c9-painkkkiller.c9.io to port 8080 in your container. So there is no need to specify the port.

We do also support web sockets and they work in the same way. There's no need to specify another port.

The only thing you need to do is to make sure you are using the environment variables to connect to the right $IP and $PORT when starting your back-end process.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I understood about port, it can be 80 or 8080, but I still can't get how to get know right $IP. All examples I saw was taken it from process.env.IP but my frontend not hosted on Cloud9 so I have no access to environment variables. So once again I ask is it possible at all? And if possible how to do it?

Comment: The problem as far as I understood that url https://socialcrm-c9-painkkkiller.c9.io in fact not a real url, I can't ping it to get know IP. So all socket connections fails. I suppose it's impossible to do for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Old question - but I'm struggling with a similar problem. I don't have reputation to add a comment, but this should answer your question about getting the IP into your Cloud9 application.

You can reference `process.env.IP`to grab the IP... and fwiw, you can reference `process.env.PORT` to get the port.

Taken from:
https://community.c9.io/t/writing-a-node-js-app/1731